# SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer

Tags: javascript

showing errors like missing ; after for-loop. Thanks for helping.

```
 function checkAttempt(){
        var studentID = document.getElementById("studentID").value;
        var attempt = 0;

        for (attempt < 3 && studentID == localStorage.studentID){
            gradeTest;
            attempt = attempt + 1;
            localStorage.attempt = attempt;
            }       
        }
```

Comment: `for (attempt > 3 && studentID == localStorage.studentID)` you mean `if`?

Comment: Looks like you meant a `while` loop.

Comment: You want to use a `while`, not a `for`, when you have multiple conditions like that instead of just a counter.

Comment: Your code looks half-baked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `for` with `while`:

```
function checkAttempt(){
    var studentID = document.getElementById("studentID").value;
    var attempt = 0;

    while (attempt < 3 && studentID == localStorage.studentID{
        gradeTest;
        attempt = attempt + 1;
        localStorage.attempt = attempt;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but my local storage is not storing attempt, and my gradeTest function is working.

Comment: That is not the question and the code in your gradeTest function is not in the code you provided. Read the documentation on localStorage and how to call functions.